# Fetch and display cache converted native documents using REST API in relativityone?

Tags: rest, document

I am using relativity for my e-discovery purpose and I want a native html of the document . So I changed the document using document viewer services rest API and the document has converted successfully.

For converting the doc into native html I used the following link -
[To convert documents in a workspace, send a request to this URL for the Document Viewer Services](https://%3Chost%3ERelativity.REST/api/Relativity.DocumentViewer.Services.IDocumentViewerServiceModule/DocumentViewerServiceManager/GetViewerContentKeyAsync/)

Sample JSON request for native type conversion -

> {
> "request":{
> "WorkspaceId":1015349,
> "ConversionType":"Native",
> "DocumentIds":[
> 1015350
> ],
> "Priority":"OnTheFly",
> "Options":{
> "ClientId":"Relativity.Documentation.Sample"
> }
> }
> }

This API provides a cache converted index.html file . But I am unable to view and display the converted file into my document viewer pane . Please help , any help will be appreciated . Thanks in advance .